# Autosaving web forms with sisyphus not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have all my forms saved on my webpage...
I have jquery 1.8.2 and sisyphus_min.js in my js directory.
I therefore added this to my html header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sisyphus.min.js"></script>
```

Then after my form within my html body I have

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('form').sisyphus(); });
    });</script>
```

This is supposed to be very straightforward but it does not work... Am I putting the $('form').sisyphus(); call in the wrong place or the wrong way?

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did any errors show up in console? Looks like you have to many parentheses. Try to remove the last line or just take this code instead yours:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('form').sisyphus(); 
    });
</script>
```